# how to combine tables in External Lists

Tags: search

I have 2 tables in my SQL database: Names and Names 2. When I make my individual ECTs for my 2 tables and create an external list in my SharePoint 2010 site, I can see both tables perfectly fine. However, when I make a 3rd ECT and give CRUD capabilities to both tables, I am unable to view both datasets in SharePoint.

What I'm eventually trying to do is crawl both tables via this "3rd ETC" that has CRUD capabilites on both tables. I'm new to SharePoint and am trying different things. I might not need a 3rd ETC for crawling but I'm just wondering.

Please Help!  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation I would suggest creating a view in SQL (assuming you have access to do this) and use that view to create your third ECT for crawling.